# What will be the REST url for a service that expose a method which takes JSONObject as parameter

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs

What I am trying to do is to expose a service which takes `JSONObject` as a parameter. Like:

```
public interface GenericJsonInputProcessing {
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public JSONObject processGenericURI(JSONObject parameter) throws Exceptions;
}
```

JSON which I need to need to send in request URI is:

```
{"ROOT": "XYZ", "number": "001", "params": { "FIRST_NAME": "memberFirstName","LAST_NAME ": "memberLastName", "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "memberEmail","REQUEST": "request","OTHER": { "OTHER_ID":"Id","TEST_DETAILS": {"Test_id": "testId"}}}}
```

Comment: I need to know what will be the URI in this case and what to do to make this work because its the ask that method should take JSONObject as parameter

Comment: URL will be http://localhost:8080/GetEntireExecutorWB/GenericJsonInputProcessing/

Comment: I tried to pass json as string and without string as jsonobject but its not intercepted in the above interface implemented class :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a **MessageBodyReader** for parsing the request body into a JSONObject.

```
@Consumes("application/json")
public class JSONReader implements MessageBodyReader<JSONObject> {

@Override
public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return type == JSONObject.class;
}

@Override
public JSONObject readFrom(Class<JSONObject> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(entityStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String jsonString = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "{}";
    JSONObject object=parseJSON(jsonString);
    return object;
}

JSONObject parseJSON(String jsonString){
    //parse jsonString and return JSONObject 
}
}
```

Depending on your JSON library you use, you must implement `parseJSON()` method

Comment: Thanks for your input , it did work now issue is with the jaxb provider used i am now using org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider and so GSON JsonObject wont work but when i used org.json.simple.JSONObject it worked. i can use MessageBodyReader  when i have to unmarshal custom format other then XML/JSON correct me if i am wrong.